# Using an instance's value for a dispatch name

Tags: orbeon, xforms

I have the following event handler and instance:

```
<xforms:action ev:event="test-event">
    <!-- do some stuff in here -->
</xforms:action>

<xforms:instance id="metadata">
    <dummy />
</xforms:instance>
```

Later, I have:

```
<xforms:setvalue ref="instance('metadata')" value="'test-event'" />
<xforms:dispatch name="instance('metadata')" target="somethingElse" />
```

How do I get the dispatch to fire off the event with name based on the value in the metadata instance? (In this case, to fire off the `test-event` event?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use an AVT in the `name` attribute. That is, if the value is between curly brackets, it will be evaluated as an XPath expression instead of being taken literally. For instance, you could write:

```
<xf:trigger id="my-trigger">
    <xf:label>Click me!</xf:label>
    <xf:message ev:event="my-event" value="'Got it!'"/>
    <xf:dispatch ev:event="DOMActivate" name="{concat('my', '-', 'event')}" target="my-trigger"/>
</xf:trigger>
```